# Are css masks supported in Firefox?

Tags: css, svg

I read somewhere that css masks can be used in Firefox with svg files, but i can't make it work... Its working flawless in chrome and safari but i had no luck with firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: As of Firefox 54 CSS masks should be supported according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks

<s>It is not supported according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks</s>

Comment: The table says it is supported now.

Comment: @lex82 Thanks. Edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

[This is how you do it in Firefox](http://robert.ocallahan.org/2008/06/applying-svg-effects-to-html-content_04.html). You apply SVG clipPaths and masks to html content. It's not the same syntax as webkit css masks but it can achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/mask

Comment: Yes, that's the article I was reading, but i can't make it work :( I will be very grateful if you can create an working example on jsfiddle. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I would assume, that support is maybe restricted to SVG content.

Answer (score 0):

Was searching for css mask found this tutorial here, may help you. Showed a different method and it works fine with Mozilla

http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking

Example- http://www.der-schepp.de/css-masking/mouse.html

Answer (score 0):

There is this jquery pluggin, I end up choosing this solution, beacuse it is also cross-browser.

http://almogbaku.github.io/imageMask/