# How to do image mask on Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, mask

I've tried to mask image with my png and it perfectly works on chrome.
However, it doens't work on Firefox.
Here is the style I used

```
-webkit-mask: url("../img/mask.png");
-o-mask: url("../img/mask.png");
-ms-mask: url("../img/mask.png");
```

Does Firefox support masking and how to do it?

Comment: Firefox doesn't support them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284286/are-css-masks-supported-in-firefox

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414348/is-there-a-moz-mask-css-property-like-webkit-mask-image). Firefox demands a .svg image..

Answer (score 3):

### PNG opacity for all browsers (old IE need PNG transparent js)

The best idea is to use png as a main image and use it as a frame 
Example:

```
<img src="mask.png" alt="PNG which will mask" id="maskedImage"/>

#maskedImage { background:url(your_image_for_masking.jpg); }
```

You can use JS for masking all images on your page:

```
var png_overlay = 'mask.png'

function pngFrame() {
var imgs = document.images;
for( var i = 0, img; img = imgs[i]; i++ ) {
    if( img.className.indexOf('frame') >= 0 ) {
        var bgSrc = img.src;
        img.style.background = "url(" + bgSrc + ")";
        img.src = png_overlay;
    }
}
}
```

### Masking for Firefox with SVG + CSS

If You can't use JS You can use SVG masking like this:

### html

```
<svg>
 <defs>
  <mask maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="masking">
    <circle fill="white" r=".35" cy=".5" cx=".5"/>
  </mask>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

### css

svg inside html

```
mask:url(#masking)
```

svg outside html

```
mask: url("svg.svg#maskid");
```