# SVG mask clipping not working in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, svg, vector-graphics

I've been trying to achieve this scrolling effect by using SVG masks. It works perfectly fine in Chrome, although it doesn't seem to work in Firefox. I've created a dabblet to show the behaviour I'm getting: http://dabblet.com/gist/83bf9a8708193634892e

The proper way to create clipping masks differs between browsers (more information about this can be found [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/)). Of course I've used both indicated methods, for Chrome and Firefox.

The SVG file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="138px" height="522.457px" viewBox="81 -111.228 138 522.457" enable-background="new 81 -111.228 138 522.457"
 xml:space="preserve">
  <path id="svgClip" d="M215.546,73.573c-4.565-16.493-28.671-31.462-35.774-40.851c-7.104-9.389-5.964-39.836-5.964-39.836v-52.268
c0,0-0.254-19.917-0.254-21.821c2.03,0,1.396-3.679,1.396-3.679s0-9.896,0-12.052c0-2.157-2.03-2.41-2.03-2.41v-7.823
c-0.509-4.061-5.242-4.061-5.242-4.061H150.93h-1.86h-16.747c0,0-4.735,0-5.243,4.061v7.823c0,0-2.03,0.254-2.03,2.41
s0,12.052,0,12.052s-0.634,3.679,1.395,3.679c0,1.903-0.253,21.821-0.253,21.821v52.268c0,0,1.142,30.447-5.962,39.836
c-7.104,9.388-31.208,24.357-35.775,40.851c-4.567,16.492-3.552,45.925-2.792,69.268l4.069,249.541c0,0-1.489,17.889,14.278,18.397
c14.653,0.798,39.683,0.339,49.664,0.108c8.501,0.23,30.053,0.689,44.705-0.108c18.605-1.015,16.94-19.623,16.94-19.623
l7.02-248.315C219.1,119.498,220.114,90.065,215.546,73.573z"/>
  <mask id="mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" transform="scale(1)">
    <path d="M215.546,73.573c-4.565-16.493-28.671-31.462-35.774-40.851c-7.104-9.389-5.964-39.836-5.964-39.836v-52.268
c0,0-0.254-19.917-0.254-21.821c2.03,0,1.396-3.679,1.396-3.679s0-9.896,0-12.052c0-2.157-2.03-2.41-2.03-2.41v-7.823
c-0.509-4.061-5.242-4.061-5.242-4.061H150.93h-1.86h-16.747c0,0-4.735,0-5.243,4.061v7.823c0,0-2.03,0.254-2.03,2.41
s0,12.052,0,12.052s-0.634,3.679,1.395,3.679c0,1.903-0.253,21.821-0.253,21.821v52.268c0,0,1.142,30.447-5.962,39.836
c-7.104,9.388-31.208,24.357-35.775,40.851c-4.567,16.492-3.552,45.925-2.792,69.268l4.069,249.541c0,0-1.489,17.889,14.278,18.397
c14.653,0.798,39.683,0.339,49.664,0.108c8.501,0.23,30.053,0.689,44.705-0.108c18.605-1.015,16.94-19.623,16.94-19.623
l7.02-248.315C219.1,119.498,220.114,90.065,215.546,73.573z"/>
  </mask>
</svg>
```

What am I doing wrong when trying to implement it on Firefox?
As usual, any kind of hint or help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: I'm developing this site locally, and the mask file is on the same directory :/

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284286/are-css-masks-supported-in-firefox) might be useful to you.

Comment: Nope, double-checked and it's not working for me :(. I even tried setting the SVG inline in the HTML document and using "mask: url(#mask);".

Comment: I'll definitely will check that out, @Shivam. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mask needs to have a fill colour set e.g.

```css
#wrapper {
 width: 600px;
 height: 600px;
 background: black;
}

#wrapper .container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;
            mask: url(#mask);
}

#wrapper .container .inner1,
#wrapper .container .inner2,
#wrapper .container .inner3 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#wrapper .container .inner1 {
 background: red;
}

#wrapper .container .inner2 {
 background: green;
}

#wrapper .container .inner3 {
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="inner1"></div>
  <div class="inner2"></div>
  <div class="inner3"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="0" height="0" viewBox="81 -111.228 138 522.457">
  <mask id="mask" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <path fill="white" d="M215.546,73.573c-4.565-16.493-28.671-31.462-35.774-40.851c-7.104-9.389-5.964-39.836-5.964-39.836v-52.268
 c0,0-0.254-19.917-0.254-21.821c2.03,0,1.396-3.679,1.396-3.679s0-9.896,0-12.052c0-2.157-2.03-2.41-2.03-2.41v-7.823
 c-0.509-4.061-5.242-4.061-5.242-4.061H150.93h-1.86h-16.747c0,0-4.735,0-5.243,4.061v7.823c0,0-2.03,0.254-2.03,2.41
 s0,12.052,0,12.052s-0.634,3.679,1.395,3.679c0,1.903-0.253,21.821-0.253,21.821v52.268c0,0,1.142,30.447-5.962,39.836
 c-7.104,9.388-31.208,24.357-35.775,40.851c-4.567,16.492-3.552,45.925-2.792,69.268l4.069,249.541c0,0-1.489,17.889,14.278,18.397
 c14.653,0.798,39.683,0.339,49.664,0.108c8.501,0.23,30.053,0.689,44.705-0.108c18.605-1.015,16.94-19.623,16.94-19.623
 l7.02-248.315C219.1,119.498,220.114,90.065,215.546,73.573z"/>
  </mask>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly fine after I added a fill color.

Comment: Wow thanks, what huge difference a tiny detail can make.

Comment: For future peeps! The fill he's talking about is the `fill="white"` on the `<path>` inside `<mask>`. Thanks for the help! Weird that this makes it work.